# ui-router routing 2 different states with different templates

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui-router 0.2.10. My application has two different templates, index.html & index2.html. I've created an abstract state, and i'm referencing both indexs' in their respective states, The problem is I can access the first route fine, but when I try to access the next route it just keeps defaulting to the first route. The abstract templates live in the same folder.

What am I missing here?

```
 .config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", function(sp, urp) {

    urp.otherwise("/index1");


    sp.state("index1", {
        abstract:true,
        url: "/index1",
        templateUrl: "index.html" 
    });
    sp.state("index1.id", {
        url: "/id",
        template: "views/partials/index.partial.html",
        controller: function($scope,$state){
            $state.go('index1.id');

        }
    });

    sp.state("index2", {
        abstract:true,
        url: "/index2",
        templateUrl: "index2.html"
    });
    sp.state("index2.id", {
        url: "/id",
        template: "views/partials/index2.partial.html",
        controller: function($scope,$state){
            $state.go('index2.id');

        }
    });

}])
```

Comment: The code seems to be using `template` and `templateUrl` interchangeably; however,  `template` is supposed to contain raw HTML, while `templateURL` points to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're trying to go to an abstract state and that won't work as abstract states will only be activated when you go to a child of that abstract state, i.e. you can't direct go to `index1` or `index2`, so this is not legal:

`urp.otherwise("/index1");` it should be: `urp.otherwise("/index1/id");` instead.

also why are you going to the states again within their own controller?  `$state.go('index2.id');` is pointless since by the time that line of code is `reached` you are already in the state `index2.id`. I think you meant to put those lines of code inside the controllers of the abstract states! Last bit not least don't forget that your abstract states *MUST* have a `ui-view` themselves as they are hosting child states.

[See plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/3tg14Rwa10RMwRZ7br2I?p=preview).

Comment: Hi Mohammad, thanks for answering my question, you're a life saver. I realise my mistake now. I have one question though, besides my abstract states not having a ui-view was the way I declared each state causing any issue? as in sp.state... ?

Comment: Not really, everything looks OK, aside from calling $sate.go to go to the same state that the controller is in as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: btw, If my answer helped you you can accept it by clicking the tick next to it ;)